# Find overlapping ranges based on positions in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets:

```
 chr1 25 85
 chr1 2000 3000
 chr2 345 2300
```

and the 2nd,

```
chr1 34 45 1.2
chr1 100 1000
chr2 456 1500 1.3
```

This is my desired output,

```
chr1 25 85 1.2
chr2 345 2300 1.3
```

Below is my code:

```
sb <- NULL
rangesC <- NULL
sb$bin <- NULL
for(i in levels(df1$V1)){
   s <- subset(df1, df1$V1 == i)
   sb <- subset(df2, df2$V1 == i)
   for(j in 1:nrow(sb)){
     sb$bin[j] <-s$V4[(s$V2 <= sb$V2[j] & s$V3 >= sb$V3[j])]
  }
 rangesC <- try(rbind(rangesC, sb),silent = TRUE)
}
```

The error I get is :

```
replacement has length zero OR when I use as.character rangesC is empty.
```

I would like to get the V4 corresponding if the positions overlap. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foverlaps()` function from the `data.table` package does an *overlap join* of two data.tables:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = names(df1))
setDT(df2, key = key(df1))
foverlaps(df2, df1, nomatch = 0L)[, -c("i.V2", "i.V3")]
```

> ```
>      V1  V2   V3  V4
> 1: chr1  25   85 1.2
> 2: chr2 345 2300 1.3
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread(
  "chr1 25 85
 chr1 2000 3000
 chr2 345 2300", header = FALSE
)

df2 <- fread(
  "chr1 34 45 1.2
chr1 100 1000 
chr2 456 1500 1.3", header = FALSE
)
```